# Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019

Tags: oracle11g

I have a question related to oracle. I have a machine which earlier had Oracle client installed on it. I was able to connect to my oracle server using the client.

Now I recently installed oracle 11g DB on the same machine. Now I have one client and Oracle 11g DB installed. But some how I am not able to connect to oracle servers anymore. This seems a bit problem because I am getting two oracle homes and stuff in path and registry entry.

The error that I am getting while connecting is 
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019

Note: I had a similar problem once but once I uninstalled the oracle DB server and
removed the ORACLE_HOME entries things started working fine.

Could you please help me fix this problem. Do let me know if you need more information

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Well,

Just worked it out. While having both installations we have two ORACLE_HOME directories and both have SQAORA32.dll files. While looking up for ORACLE_HOMe my app was getting confused..I just removed the Client oracle home entry as oracle client is by default present in oracle DB Now its working...Thanks!!

Comment: That was exactly my case, I had an Oracle Client and then I installed XE, after that I couldn't connect to another application using Oracle and receiving the same error. Once I uninstalled the client as you did it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: I had an instant client directory and another client installed in my C:\oracle\ and apparently it tried to use the instant client directory but all other stuff like sqlplus/tnsping etc used the installed client. Grrr.. well thanks you put me on the right track..

Comment: Received the same error. Solution was to change Oracle provider in connection string.

Answer (score 4):

Correct the ORACLE_HOME path.

There could be two oracle clients in the system.

I had the same issue, the reason being my ORACLE_HOME was pointed to the oracle installation which was not having the tns.ora file.

Changing the ORACLE_HOME to the Oracle directory which is having the tns.ora solved it.

tns.ora lies in client2\network\admin\

Answer (score 2):

### WHEN ORA-01019 ERROR OCCURS

1. Check with TNSPING , if not responding then add Service Name entry in tns.ora file.
2. Check firewall, if enabled then disable it.
3. Add Env. variable ORACLE_HOME to the Path of oracle client directory up to 'c:\oracle...\client1', this solution will definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. My solution was delete one of the oracle path in environment variable. I also changed the inventory.xml and point to the oracle home version which is in my environment path variable.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just needed to install oracle 10g client on the server, becase there there was the 11g version.

Ps: I don't needed unistall nothing, I just install the 10g version and updated the tnsnames file (C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN)

Answer (score 0):

I was having this error with SSIS SSDT. The fix was to use a provider of ".Net Providers\OracleClient Data Provider" instead of OLEDB

Answer (score -1):

You can refer to this [link](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminogic/archive/2016/12/26/steps-to-connect-ssis-to-oracle).

Install ODAC 64 bit driver using CMD after install ODAC 32 bit:

1. Go to ODAC  bit folder where install.bat file is located using CMD.
2. Type `install.bat all c:/oracle odac` command and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

   Installation file will be located at “c:/oracle” folder.

When installing Oracle 11g client 32 and 64 bit, you must change oracle base path: “c:/oracle”