# Connect Oracle Database with Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle, visual-studio-2012

I use visual studio Express 2012 for Web and install ODTwithODAC1210 (oracle client), but the oracle client cannot integrate with visual studio. When I select Data source as "Oracle Database", there is only one Data provider ".Net Framework Data Provider for OLE DATA DB".

When I fillout all information, and test connection, I get following error:

```
Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019
```

Any one know how to solve this problem. I very need a hlep.

Comment: check out here , already done http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019

Comment: I didn't work in my case... I already saw it before

Comment: so you already have the ODT but the data provider doesn't appear in the list, are you an admin on this machine, can you try a fresh install with elevated privileges

Comment: the definition of ora-01019 is                                ORA-01019: unable to allocate memory in the user side
Cause: The user side memory allocator returned an error.
Action:. Increase the size of the process heap or switch to the old set of calls.

Comment: check out this link http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/databases/oracle/threads/27897/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019        seems like this issue happens when you have had an oracle installation before or an older version of ODAT were there in the machine before this install.

Answer (score 0):

I too had this problem. I think this is mainly related to the procedure while installing oracle on your pc. And oracle sucks up big time connecting with visual studio.

I>

1) Download the 'Oracle developer tools for visual studio' link while creating a new server connection. (U can find this link on the right side where you are getting that ".Net Framework Data Provider for OLE DATA DB" option)
2) Uninstall oracle
3)now install oracle again and those tools u have downloaded.

II>

1) Or U can use Oracle XE plugin (google it, its around 160 MB) and carefully enter your username and passwords.
2) Now try to link it from VS.

Hope this help somewhat.

NOTE:- Still I dont recommend oracle with visual studio because even if you get a success in trying all above. But While writing a 'connection string' for DB in VS. Its again will give some kind of errors: such as word 'UNICODE' is not recognized, etc.