# Error ORA-01019 while trying to retrieve text ORA-01019

Tags: c++, vb.net, oracle

I have a issue with `Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable`.

We already have a latest version of VC++ 8.0.59193 installed.

somehow 8.0.56336 installed recently, we have no idea on how it had installed.

We have a .vbs script and same was working before version 8.0.56336 was installed.

our script throws error of Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; but the same script worked before cv++ 8.0.56336 installed.

```
VBError:- Run-TIme error '-2147467259 (80004005)';
[Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle]Error while trying to 
retrieve text for error ORA-01019
```

I am new to vb scripting so I don't want to modify the script as it was working.

My doubt is that" is the version change impact to ODBC connection?"

How to get ride of this problem?

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019) could be helpful

Comment: Issue has resolved ended up changing the code as required, I hope ti will be helpful for some one. strCon = "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle}; " & _ 
"CONNECTSTRING=(DESCRIPTION=" & _ 
"(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)" & _ 
"(HOST=" & d_db_host & ")(PORT=" & d_db_port & "))" & _ 
"(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=" & d_db_service_name & "))); uid=" & d_db_user & "; pwd=" & d_db_password & ";" 

Change to: 

strCon = "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;User ID="& d_db_user & ";Password=" & d_db_password & ";Data Source=" & d_db_service_name & ";"