# Access DB ODBC Call Failed

Tags: sql, ms-access, odbc

I have been tasked with moving one of our old DBs into an Access DB. I imported 17 of my 24 tables successfully and received an error stating

> Cannot open database . It may not be a database that your
>   application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt

Tried again, same result. Noticed the DB was over 2GB so I opened a new access DB to import my other 7 tables to see if it was the tables or the fact that I had too much data going in. When I tried to import the 7 in the new DB I received the following error:

> ODBC--call failed.  [Microsoft][ODBC driver for Oracle][Oracle] Error
>   while trying to retreive text for error
>   ORA-01019(#1019)[Microsfot][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's
>   SQLSetConnectAttr failed IM006 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]
>   Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed (#0)

Thought that was odd so I moved back to the previous database and attempted to import again even though I knew I'd receive the first error message, but it surprisingly displayed the second error message (ODBC--call failed).

Did some research on what it may be, but I'm at a complete loss. Why would this work one time and not the next? Note that I still receive the same error from other DSN connections as well.

Comment: You should share more details about what "import" means.  **What tool?  What options did you use?**  Also, if you attempted to reduce the dataset by importing a reduced set into another database, why not go further and attempt to import just *one table* into a new DB?  Start very simply when debugging.  Baby steps.  Don't try to execute the biggest step possible, especially if you are "at a complete loss".

Comment: C Perkins,

I'm attempting to import tables from a database using an ODBC Oracle driver. I am using MS Access 2016. How I'm attempting to import the tables is through the tab External Data > New Data Source > From SQL Server > Import the source data into a new table in the current database > From the Machine Data Sources tab I choose my DSN. It then asks me for my credentials. When I input my credentials and hit OK that's when I get the error ODBC call failed error above. The problem is I can't import any tables because I can't find the source of why this connection is failing.

Comment: Sometimes it will randomly work for one import and then fail the rest of the day. I've been able to import two tables now successfully, but it hasn't worked for me since then. 

I apologize for not being very detailed, was just wondering if anyone has seen this error before and what they had for a solution. The error indicates to me that it's something to do with the driver itself.

Comment: No need to apologize, but a good question will always included the type of detail you provided in your comment.  Also, this type of detail should be added to the actual question by editing the question.  Perhaps rarely someone might recognize a particular error, but more often an error can occur in different situations so that context is required.  Finally, if you are wondering about an error then search for the error code.  I just did that and found [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019) among many others.

Comment: Of the various pages that I found, there are at least 4 possible things that you can try / configure / test.  As part of your research, did you try any suggestions that you found?  If so, what was it and what was the result?  Such details are all part of [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).