# How to input info to a remote Oracle Application with excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, oracleapplications

In my previous job I used to input data into SAP using excel VBA and setting up the connection was fairly easy.

I'm now looking for a way to do the same with Oracle, the issue is that I don't have any client installed in my PC, we access the Oracle applications remotely via Browser.

What do I need to look for to set this up? Also, is there a script recorder for Oracle Applications that I could just copy the code into VBA?

I tried following this question as an example ([Connection from VBA to Oracle DB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56618817/connection-from-vba-to-oracle-db)) but there is no Oracle client on my pc.

Comment: If you typically access the application via a web browser front-end, then you're likely stuck with something like automating a browser using (eg) Selenium Basic.  https://florentbr.github.io/SeleniumBasic/

Comment: Press F12 in your browser, find the network tab and follow it closely when updating. If you manage to filter out your updates, you might be able to replicate it.