# Problems with connection to Oracle SQL from a .NET console app

Tags: .net, oracle, oracle11g

I have this code:

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=192.168.117.1;User ID=*****;Password=*****;Unicode=True");
con.Open();

OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from BAKASHOT_PIRTY_MEIDA", con);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
oda.Fill(dt);

con.Close();
```

[image]

All I'm trying to do is to put the query inside a table var. My server explorer recognizes the connection, but the second line throws an error:

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-01019'

I'm kinda lost. I've been trying for the past 2 hours to connect to my database from the app.

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12560925/error-while-trying-to-retrieve-text-for-error-ora-01019

Comment: saw that one but theres no detailed explanation and I couldnt find the path in my pc

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: The MSDAORA provider is very old and [deprecated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675851%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for ages, I don't know whether it supports the [Easy Connect Naming Method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/ntcli/specifying-a-connection-by-using-the-easy-connect-naming-method.html). You many use another provider/driver, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34803106/how-to-connect-to-oracle-11-database-from-net/34805999#34805999

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Data Source` must be an Oracle database name.

Use either

- the full name, e.g. `(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=192.168.117.1)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=sales_us))`
- or an alias which is typically resolved by `tnsnames.ora` file
- or by Easy Connect, e.g.  `192.168.117.1:1521<port>`

Comment: if I do that    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection("DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = tcp)(HOST = 192.168.117.1)(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = XE)");
what I get is :
System.ArgumentException: 'An OLE DB Provider was not specified in the ConnectionString.  An example would be, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.'

Comment: I did not write "the connection string must be..." , I wrote the "Data Source must be..." see https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/